# Unexpected values in DataFrame after reshaping

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

So, I have the following reshape function:

```
reshaped <- function(df){
df %>%
  select(subjects, diseases) %>% 
  group_by(subjects, diseases) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(diseases, n, drop=TRUE)}
```

which essentially spreads the data from long to wide, filling the entries with number of occurrences or NA values. Now, when I spread this and print to console I get something like:

```
subject    disease1  disease2  disease3 ...
1111111        2         3         1
1111112        21        4         2
1111115        2         1         15
1111117        1         3         1
```

Now, the problem is, these numbers are false. Subject `1111111` does not have 2 instances of `disease1` or 3 instances of `disease2`, etc. All the entries should be filled with NA values. In fact, these `disease_1, disease2, disease3` are super-rare diseases which rarely occur at all throughout the data, but just happen to come first in the alphabetical order (all start with A).

There are some other things to be aware of. First, this is an extremely large dataset with the reshaped version having around 38,000 columns and 1.2 million rows. I use around 400 GB RAM to process this data (in chunks) and it weighs around 117 GB in compressed RDs format. I do not get any memory errors, however. Interestingly, when I sample, say, random 100,000 subjects (rows), this issue disappears. The numbers that I see are quite realistic (mostly NAs). This suggests that the problem is not with the function itself or the data, but with the observation size.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening or how I can solve this? To me, it looks like some form of overflow where R doesn't know what to do when the data size is too big and just puts garbage values there. The problem with this hypothesis is that these values, although unreasonable, are not entirely random. They are all less than 10 or so.

Comment: Can you please show a small reprouducible example with expected output. thanks

Comment: @akrun thanks for having a look! The problem is that with reproducible, small examples I randomly sample there is no issues. The function works perfectly fine. When the observation numbers start to get big (e.g. 500,000 - 1 mln), things start to go wrong.

Comment: That is strange.  Can you try `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df)[, .N, .(subjects, diseases)], subjects + diseases ~ N)`

Comment: FYI, the select-group-count can be reduced to `df %>% count(subjects, diseases) %>%`

Comment: Also, can you try with `pivot_wider` i.le. `pivot_wider(names_from = diseases, value_from = n)`

Comment: Not sure if this was your issue, but your `function()` references a `subjects` column, but the output in your post references a `subject` column.  This probably was just a typo, but in case this was copied, you may want to check that out.  I was able to get you function to work on [this data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv) changing `subjects` to `region` and `diseases` to `countryName`.

Comment: @JoshuaMire, no this was just a dummy example where I made a typo. The function works well with small dataframes. When I put bigger values, it starts giving me irrelevant, crazy values.

Comment: it would be good if you want this question to be answered, to include code for generating sample inputs. If you could create code which generates n number of rows, where n is the number above which you start having trouble, that would be great!